# Cygwin pkg-config/protobuf filepath issues

Tags: c++, cygwin, pkg-config, protobuf-c

I'm trying to compile & install a C++ library using Cygwin. I've properly installed the library's dependencies. However, ./configure is throwing an error:

checking for protobuf... no
    configure: error: Package requirements (protobuf >= 3.3) were not met:

No package 'protobuf' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you 
    installed software in a non-standard prefix.

I then checked config.log, and found a suggestion to point `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` at the `lib/pkgconfig` directory. I promptly set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, the directory where `protobuf.pc` is located on my system. The error persisted. Some checking of similar questions here showed that some people had to use the Windows filepath, so I switched `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `c:\\cygwin64\\usr\\local\\lib\\pkgconfig`. The error persisted. I even tried setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`. Which didn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Since I can't comment yet, I guess I need to leave this as an answer?)

After installing the libprotobuf-devel package from the cygwin setup.exe, I could run `pkg-config --list-all` and see `protobuf` listed in the output. Also, `pkg-config --print-provides protobuf` returns `protobuf = 3.3.1`. Are you getting the same output?

I would also look at the `configure` script to see what it's trying to check. Opening up `configure` and searching for `protobuf` or `checking for protobuf` should get you close to the actual check. Maybe `configure` is trying to do something weird.

Lastly, at least on my cygwin install, I do not have a `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` directory. If you installed protobuf from source, maybe you could try the cygwin devel package (libprotobuf-devel) and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realized I could install protobuf through setup.exe-I had done it manually, which is probably what caused the problem in the first place. This issue, at least, is fixed.